# Keras load_weights() not loading checkpoints

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have been following the RNN tutorial of Tensorflow
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation

The model.load_weights() is not working, and is throwing the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/swati.srivastava/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow Practice/main.py", line 1232, in <module>
    model.load_weights(tf.train.load_checkpoint("./training_checkpoints/ckpt_" + str(checkpoint_num)))
  File "C:\Users\swati.srivastava\PycharmProjects\TensorFlow Practice\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2260, in load_weights
    filepath, save_format = _detect_save_format(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\swati.srivastava\PycharmProjects\TensorFlow Practice\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2868, in _detect_save_format
    if saving_utils.is_hdf5_filepath(filepath):
  File "C:\Users\swati.srivastava\PycharmProjects\TensorFlow Practice\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saving_utils.py", line 327, in is_hdf5_filepath
    return (filepath.endswith('.h5') or filepath.endswith('.keras') or
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.util._pywrap_checkpoint_reader.C' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code is

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64 
VOCAB_SIZE = len(vocab)
EMBEDDING_DIM = 256
RNN_UNITS = 1024
def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(rnn_units,
                             return_sequences=True,
                             stateful=True,
                             recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
    ])
    return model

checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
    save_weights_only=True
)


model = build_model(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, RNN_UNITS, batch_size=1)

checkpoint_num = 2
model.load_weights(tf.train.load_checkpoint("./training_checkpoints/ckpt_" + str(checkpoint_num)))
model.build(tf.TensorShape([1, None]))
```

My project directory looks like

[image: Project Directory]

which means that the training checkpoints are created, and exist. None of the checkpoint files are empty.

The only solution I could find was at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38745, where it says to do `save_weights_only=True`, which I have already done.

I think it is some sort of version conflict, but am not sure.

Edit: Added the checkpoint_callback snippet. `training_checkpoints` directory is created as can be seen in the project directory image

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `load_weights` [api](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights) expects an HDF5 format file, but as per the your code, you do not provide it.

I am assuming that you are using `ModelCheckpoint` API for checkpoint creation like below:

```
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)
```

Then you will just provide the checkpoint path which is in your case `'./training_checkpoints/'`

```
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
```

You can look at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) for more details.

Comment: I am doing exactly what is mentioned in the documentation, but still getting this error. I also know that there is an issue with the file format, but can't pin point as to what is the issue. As mentioned by you, I am writing the code snippets like this only. Could you please suggest any other solution?

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible code to analyse this issue, preferably in google colab.  @SwatiSrivastava

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ysEKrw_LE2jMndo1snrZUh5w87LQsCxk#forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true
Above is the tutorial I'm following. It gave an error in the ```model.load_weights``` in the ending part..